# Estoy intentando resolver problemas de programacion lineal con pulp ingresando variables

Tags: python

estoy intentando hacer un programa que resuelva ejercicios de programación lineal usando la libreria pulp donde yo pueda ingresar los datos tanto de la función objetivo como el numero de restricciones que tendrá. Este es un ejemplo pero donde ya los datos están dentro del código

```
from pulp import *  

# Crear un problema de maximización
problem = LpProblem("Ejemplo_Programacion_Lineal", LpMaximize)

# Definir las variables
x = LpVariable('x', lowBound=0)  # Variable x >= 0
y = LpVariable('y', lowBound=0)  # Variable y >= 0

# Función objetivo
# Ejemplo: Max 3x + 5y
objective_function = 3*x + 5*y
problem += objective_function

# Restricciones
# Ejemplo: 
# 2x + 3y <= 12
# 4x - y >= 2
problem += (2*x + 3*y <= 12, "restriccion_1")
problem += (4*x - y >= 2, "restriccion_2")

# Resolver el problema
problem.solve()

# Imprimir resultados
print(f"Status: {problem.status}")
print(f"Función objetivo: {objective_function.value()}")
print(f"Valor de x: {x.value()}")
print(f"Valor de y: {y.value()}")
```

Ahora este es el código donde yo ingreso los datos para resolver el ejercicio que yo quiera pero cuando mando a imprimir los resultados me da todo 0 no se cual sea mi error.

```
from pulp import *

# Crea un problema de maximización
problem = LpProblem("Programacion Lineal", LpMaximize)

# Definir las variables de decisión
variables = ['X1', 'X2']

# Definir las variables
x1 = LpVariable('X1', lowBound=0)  # Variable x1 >= 0
x2 = LpVariable('X2', lowBound=0)  # Variable x2 >= 0

print("Ingresa la funcion objetivo\n")
num_x1 = float(input("Valor X1: "))
num_x2 = float(input("Valor X2: "))

# Función objetivo
objective_function = num_x1 * x1 + num_x2 * x2
problem += objective_function

num_restricciones = int(input("Ingrese el número de restricciones: "))

for i in range(num_restricciones):
    constraint_coeffs = [float(input(f"Coeficiente para {variable}: ")) for variable in variables]

    operator = input("Operador (<=, >=, =): ")
    constraint_value = float(input("Valor de la restricción: "))  # Renombrar para evitar conflicto

    constraint_name = f"restriccion_{i + 1}"
    if operator == "<=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) <= constraint_value, constraint_name
    elif operator == ">=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) >= constraint_value, constraint_name
    elif operator == "=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) == constraint_value, constraint_name

problem.solve()

# Imprimir resultados
print(f"Status: {problem.status}")
print(f"Función objetivo: {objective_function.value()}")
print(f"Valor de x1: {x1.value()}")
print(f"Valor de x2: {x2.value()}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en `lpSum(constraint_coeffs)`, donde `constraint_coeffs` es una lista con los coeficientes de las variables de las restricciones, pero a `lpSum` debes darle los términos (coeficiente y su variable).

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
from pulp import *

# Crea un problema de maximización
problem = LpProblem("Programacion Lineal", LpMaximize)


# Definir las variables
x1 = LpVariable('X1', lowBound=0)  # Variable x1 >= 0
x2 = LpVariable('X2', lowBound=0)  # Variable x2 >= 0
variables = [x1, x2]

print("Ingresa la funcion objetivo\n")
num_x1 = float(input("Valor X1: "))
num_x2 = float(input("Valor X2: "))

# Función objetivo
objective_function = num_x1 * x1 + num_x2 * x2
problem += objective_function

num_restricciones = int(input("Ingrese el número de restricciones: "))

for i in range(num_restricciones):
    constraint_coeffs = [float(input(f"Coeficiente para {variable.name}: ")) * variable for variable in variables]

    operator = input("Operador (<=, >=, =): ")
    constraint_value = float(input("Valor de la restricción: "))  # Renombrar para evitar conflicto

    constraint_name = f"restriccion_{i + 1}"
    match operator:
        case "<=":
            problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) <= constraint_value, constraint_name
        case ">=":
            problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) >= constraint_value, constraint_name
        case "=":
            problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) == constraint_value, constraint_name

problem.solve()

# Imprimir resultados
print(f"Status: {problem.status}")
print(f"Función objetivo: {objective_function.value()}")
print(f"Valor de x1: {x1.value()}")
print(f"Valor de x2: {x2.value()}")
```